# I tried to use Days Between in pig but I get error

Tags: apache-pig

I tried to use Days Between in pig but I get an error.

> `ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias test`

```html
rental =  LOAD './rental.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (rental_id:int , rental_date:chararray, inventory_id:int , customer_id:int, return_date:chararray,staff_id:int);


test = foreach rental GENERATE rental_id,  DaysBetween(ToDate(rental.return_date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),
   ToDate(rental.rental_date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

dump test;
```

If I remove daysBetween function dumping test will work. I found many examples but it does not work.

EXAMPLE of date format 2016-05-24 22:54:33

Answer (score 0):

Cast the result of ToDate i.e. (datetime)

```
test = foreach rental GENERATE rental_id,  DaysBetween((datetime)ToDate(rental.return_date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),(datetime)ToDate(rental.rental_date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

dump test;
```

**EDIT**
It works,see below

```
1,2016-05-24 22:54:33,2015-04-24 22:54:33
2,2016-04-24 22:54:33,2014-03-24 22:54:33
3,2016-03-24 22:54:33,2011-02-24 22:54:33
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried this before and it does not work. same error

Comment: It works,I've edited the posted and included an example